# Projeto só roda se o Visual Studio estiver instalado na maquina cliente

Tags: .net, web-service, wpf, iis, asp.net-web-api

Olá.
Tenho um projeto feito em WPF, que usa dados retornados por web services para interagir com o usuario.
Esse sistema, ao iniciar, consulta o IIS pra ver se o mesmo está de pé, se os web services estão lá e se estão operantes, se não estiver ele lança uma pergunta pro usuario se deseja continuar.
Pois bem, buildamos em release, copiamos a pasta e colocamos em outra maquina, sem o VS instalado, e pra nossa surpresa não funcionou, ele não consultou mas também não deu erros, tentamos atualizar o IIS, instalar todas versões do .NET Framework e nada, até que resolvemos instalar o VS, e logo antes de terminar a instalação já estava funcionando.
Ativamos também os logs através do registro, mas em nenhum dos logs registrados mostrou algo de anormal.
Alguém já passou por isso? Existe algum pacote essencial que devo baixar antes de rodar minha aplicação?

Atualização:
 - Verifiquei as versões, estão identicas, o que muda é que eu programo em Win8 e no cliente é um Win7, não sei se tem algo a ver, mas os NET Framework instalados são iguais.Quando executo, ele não dá erro nenhum, aparece a tela principal mas nada funciona nela.
 - Vou tentar o esquema do debug remoto e qualquer coisa posto aqui.

Comment: Ja tentaram fazer *debug* remoto do projecto instalado no cliente para ver o que se passa? Veja aqui como configurar [*debug* remoto](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bt727f1t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Verifique o .NET versão instaladas nas maquinas tem que ser igual ou superior a do projeto. Quando você roda no cliente qual é o erro na hora de execução, porque, na hora da execução ele vai te falar alguma coisa? Poste na sua questão!!!

Comment: Questão atualizada

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problema resolvido: Por algum motivo meu sistema está procurando o IIS express, que só é habilitado com o VS instalado (ou manualmente pelo proprio IIS), sendo assim, sem VS ele não funcionava porque nao encontrava nenhum IIS, mas não dava erros também.
Agora é resolver esse.
Fica ai a dica pra quem tiver o problema.